# Kill python script, and restart

Tags: python, automation

Currently, I have this script which if it errors, it completely restarts. Which is perfect for what I need.

But there is one problem, I want the script to automatically restart, even when it did not crash. every 30 seconds.

This is what I have:

```
while True:
    try:
        do_main_logic()
    except:
        pass
```

I am expecting for it to just restart the entire script every 30 seconds and start from the begin. Even if it has not crashed or not.

Comment: maybe this can help? https://tenacity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ especially `@retry(wait=wait_fixed(2))`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to restart each 30 second, maybe you can do a sort of:

```
import time

while True:
    try:
        do_main_logic()
    except:
        pass
    finally:
        time.sleep(30)
```

In this way at the end of the while, in both cases you hit the `try` or the `except` the script will sleep for 30 second.

Comment: what if I want to restart it even if it has not crashed yet?

Comment: @Wout Since the `while True` generates an endless loop, in each iteration is launched the `do_main_logic()` inside the `try`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to add time.sleep(30)

```
import time
    
while True:
    time.sleep(30)
    try: 
        do_main_logic()
    except:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is `threading.Timer`. To use `Timer`, You can modify your `do_main_logic()` in the following way:

```
from threading import Timer

def do_main_logic():
    running = True
    def Timeout():
        nonlocal running
        running = False
    Timer(30, Timeout).start()
    while running: # and your loop conditions
        # your code here
```

You need to find a suitable place to constantly check the variable `running`.

Comment: But this doesn't stop the script after 30 seconds and restarts it.

Comment: @Wout, after 30 seconds, the variable `running` will be set to `False`. I guess you main_logic will contain a Time-consuming loop.  Add `running` to your loop conditions may work.