# Stop python script every 60 seconds and restart

Tags: python

This script loops and even if it crashes it restarts.

Now I want it to restart the script even if it has NOT CRASHED yet.

```
while True:
    try:
        do_main_logic()
    except:
        pass
```

I have the loop that restart on crash, but I want it to restart on 60 seconds.

Comment: Your friend posted this yesterday --https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74412665/kill-python-script-and-restart

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kill python script, and restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74412665/kill-python-script-and-restart)

Answer (score -1):

You can do this :

```
from time import sleep
    while True:
    try:
        do_main_logic()
    except:
        sleep(60)
        pass
```

Answer (score -1):

It is pretty hard to understand what you are asking for but i can still show how if works:

```
while True:
try:
    #Try to do something
except:
    #if it failed
else:
    #if it succeded
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).